# Get Output in CSV-File

Tags: python

This code outputs me the news items related to the keyword 'Airlines' from Google News, which were published within a day. Here I get the title, the description and the URL.
I have question: I would like to output the results from my console in tabular form in a CSV file, can anyone help me with this?

Thanks a lot!

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
import csv

googlenews = GoogleNews()

googlenews.set_encode('utf_8')
googlenews.set_lang('de')
googlenews.set_period('1d')
googlenews.get_news('Airlines')

print(googlenews.results())
´´´
```

Comment: Look at the documentation of [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: What is the question lol, what are you having trouble with?

Comment: The question is: Can someone help me to put this output in tabular form into a CSV file?

Comment: The output is the following: [{'title': 'American Airlines Group Inc. stock rises Monday, still underperforms market', 'desc': 'bookmark_border', 'date': '34 minutes ago', 'datetime': None, 'link': 'news.google.com/./articles/CBMihAFodHRwczovL3d3dy5tYXJrZXR3YXRjaC5jb20vc3RvcnkvYW1lcmljYW4tYWlybGluZXMtZ3JvdXAtaW5jLXN0b2NrLXJpc2VzLW1vbmRheS1zdGlsbC11bmRlcnBlcm
I have deleted some of the output, cause its really long. But that is the format I get and all this is given in a single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it in pure Python using a context manager and the `csv` module :

```py
import csv

keys = googlenews.results()[0].keys()
with open('people.csv', 'w', newline='')  as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(googlenews.results())
```

Then, as requested in the comment section, to get rid of the `Desc`, `Images` and `Media` columns, we can use the `pandas` library :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df.drop(['Desc', 'Images', 'Media'], axis=1)
df.head()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I get the following Error:     f.write(googlenews.results())
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list

Comment: Hi @DeanJames ! Can you share the output of the `print` from your code ? It will help me to try the code properly.

Comment: As the error says that `googlenews.results()` is a list, I adapted the answer with the context manager, does it work ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it only works partially. I get the CSV now, but the cells now contain the following words:
"Desc", "Date", "Datetime", "link".

Comment: Ok I just saw that you gave an output in the comment and that the output is a list of dict. I re-updated the answer, is it better ?

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It works, I am really happy right now :) Thanks

Comment: Happy to help you @DeanJames ! Glad that it works !

Comment: Is there any option to get the same cs without the columns: Desc, Images and Media? :)

Comment: I think so ! For that I will probably use the `pandas` library. Do you want to make a new question with an input of data ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post a new question today because the limit is reached ... Would it be possible that you post me the answer? :)

Comment: To give you a way to do it, you can use [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to load the data and then you can use the [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) method to get rid of the columns you mention in your comment. Tomorrow I will be able to help you on that if you want to post a new question. Just copy the link of it in this comment section.

Comment: I do it blindly without data but I added the code in the answer, hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mate! But I get a lot of these errors right now:  raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
KeyError: "['Desc' 'Images' 'Media'] not found in axis"